# Add a php GET variable on an onclick window.location from a button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a button like this :

```
<button class="buttons" onclick="window.location='page_test.php?VAR=1&VAR2=2'">BUTTON 1</button>
<button class="buttons" onclick="window.location='page_test.php?VAR=1&VAR2=2'">BUTTON 2</button>
```

How can I use javascript code to add `&VAR3=3` to the onclick to have :

```
<button class="buttons" onclick="window.location='page_test.php?VAR=1&VAR2=2&VAR3=3'">BUTTON 1</button>
<button class="buttons" onclick="window.location='page_test.php?VAR=1&VAR2=2&VAR3=3'">BUTTON 2</button>
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you're modifying the URL from frontend, rather than backend?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the current URL the user is navigating on is "`page_test.php?VAR=1&VAR2=2`", then this code would append `&VAR3=3` to the URL:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="buttons" onclick="insertParam('VAR3', '3')">BUTTON 1</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function insertParam(key, value)
{
    key = encodeURI(key); 
    value = encodeURI(value);
    var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    var i=kvp.length; 
    var x; 
    while(i--) 
    {
       x = kvp[i].split('=');
       if (x[0]==key)
       {
          x[1] = value;
          kvp[i] = x.join('=');
          break;
       }
    }

    if(i<0) 
    {
       kvp[kvp.length] = [key,value].join('=');
    }

    document.location.search = kvp.join('&'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

Like Max Voisard, assuming the current URL the user is navigating on is `"page_test.php?VAR=1&VAR2=2"`, im going to try to do it a bit simple.

```
<button class="buttons" onclick="insertParam('VAR3', '3')">BUTTON 1</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function insertParam(key, value)
{
  key   = encodeURI(key); 
  value = encodeURI(value);
  return window.location.href + `&${ key }=${ value }` 
}
```